# CSS clip-path with Pseudo class for making a custom footer

Tags: html, css

i need a little help to hack a css to make a footer for a custom website with pseudo-class and clip-path.  So i got some trouble to get it works the way it shoulb be. The footer is made with two differents colors. I made some search to see some appropriate answers; i didn't find. I'm not too far but i can't get yet what i want.

my CSS file:

```css
.footer_style{
  position: relative;
 margin: 1rem auto;
 min-height: 400px;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column nowrap;
 align-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background: #232323;
 // clip-path: polygon(51% 9%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 1% 100%, 0 19%);
 &:before{
   content: '';
   z-index: -1;
   position: absolute;
   top: -26px;
   left: -11px;
   right: 30px;
   bottom: 30px;
   -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 99%, 0 19%);
   clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 99%, 0 19%);
   background: #0465e3;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
   transform: rotate(6deg);
   height: 126px;
 }
}
```

Here is the result i'm expected :

[image]

Any help would be appreciate. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clip-path` is [not well supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) in browsers yet.

What's about simple `linear-gradient` solution?

```css
body {background:#eef}

footer {
  height: 400px;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(-7deg, #234 395px, transparent 396px), linear-gradient(7deg, #06f 395px, #fff 396px);
}
```

```html
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Thx bro! you save my life!

Comment: @Emmann, happy to help!

Comment: you don't really need `0/cover`, you can delete it

Comment: @TemaniAfif, yes!

Comment: @temaniAfif, it appears to be a duplicate question but if you test it ..you will not have the same result when you need to put content text in it...i needed a custom footer with only a small part of blue color..the answer of Kosh was perfect to me...